# How to split image to RGB channels in Tensorflow

Tags: image, image-processing, tensorflow

I want to split an RGB image into 3 channels to perform some operations on them (convert to YUV, to be more precise)  and then join them again. This is what I have done so far (this code does not work as I get dimension errors):

```
    def rgb_to_yuv(rgb):
        with tf.name_scope("rgb_to_yuv"):
            rgb = check_image(rgb) #check the number of channels
            rgb_pixels = tf.reshape(rgb, [-1, 3]) #check if the image is srgb
            r, g, b= tf.split(3, 3, rgb_pixels)
            Y = 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b
            U = 0.492 * (b - Y)
            V = 0.877 * (r - Y)
            yuv_pixels = tf.concat([Y, U, V], 1)
            return tf.reshape(yuv_pixels, tf.shape(rgb))
```

and this is check_image (from [pix2pix implementation](https://github.com/affinelayer/pix2pix-tensorflow)):

```
def check_image(image):
    assertion = tf.assert_equal(tf.shape(image)[-1], 3, message="image must have 3 color channels")
    with tf.control_dependencies([assertion]):
        image = tf.identity(image)

    if image.get_shape().ndims not in (3, 4):
        raise ValueError("image must be either 3 or 4 dimensions")

    # make the last dimension 3 so that you can unstack the colors
    shape = list(image.get_shape())
    shape[-1] = 3
    image.set_shape(shape)
    return image
```

Comment: Which version of tensorflow are you using? ``tf.split`` has undergone some changes in recent releases in the order of the arguments.